# How to disable SSL requirement in ASP.NET Core 6 Identity & SPA React app

Tags: reactjs, asp.net, asp.net-core, single-page-application, .net-6.0

I haven't been able to figure out how to disable HTTPS requirement for a new boilerplate ASP.NET Core 6 react app using Identity authentication. Has anyone been able to do it?

I've tried setting `HTTPS=false` in `.env-development` on the frontend, and on the backend removing `app.UseHttpsRedirection();` updating `launchSettings.json` to not require https, and the .csproj file `SpaProxyServerUrl` to not require https.

Now that gives me a site that kinda works, until you go to login. The oidc-client on the frontend is still requesting https links and this seems to come from the `OidcConfigurationController` on the `_configuration/<clientId>` response for open-id service endpoints. But it doesn't appear you can actually configure this anywhere with `.AddIdentityServer()`, at least not anything I've been able to find.

If I were to get tricky and just replace the urls provided by the `OidcConfigurationController` with 'http', I can get past the openid failures until the frontend makes a call to https on `https://localhost:44489/connect/authorize` and I'm not sure where https is even being specified anywhere.

The whole thing seems like a mess in terms of configuration, but I need http to work for local testing of external payment systems due to things out of my control.

Thoughts?

UPDATE: Deleting the `https://localhost:7271;` launchProfiles entry from launchSettings.json partially got me there. For some reason, calls to `.well-known/openid-configuration` gets its host/authority information from there. However, even with that the `connect/authorize` call fails on IdentityServer with the error 'Request validation failed'.

```cs
// Program.cs
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
builder.Services.AddDbContextFactory<ApplicationDbContext>(lifetime: ServiceLifetime.Scoped);
builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false)
  .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
builder.Services.AddIdentityServer()
  .AddApiAuthorization<ApplicationUser, ApplicationDbContext>();
builder.Services.AddAuthorization();
builder.Services.AddAuthentication()
  .AddIdentityServerJwt();
//app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseIdentityServer();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
app.MapRazorPages();
app.MapDefaultControllerRoute();
app.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");
```

Project file:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <SpaRoot>ClientApp\</SpaRoot>
    <DefaultItemExcludes>$(DefaultItemExcludes);$(SpaRoot)node_modules\**</DefaultItemExcludes>
    <SpaProxyServerUrl>http://localhost:44489</SpaProxyServerUrl>
    <SpaProxyLaunchCommand>npm start</SpaProxyLaunchCommand>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

```json
// launchSettings.json
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:59447",
      "sslPort": 44389
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "MyApp": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:7271;http://localhost:5271",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development",
        "ASPNETCORE_HOSTINGSTARTUPASSEMBLIES": "Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaProxy"
      }
    },
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development",
        "ASPNETCORE_HOSTINGSTARTUPASSEMBLIES": "Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaProxy"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```js
// .env.development
PORT=44489
HTTPS=false
```

```js
// setupProxy.js
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware');
const { env } = require('process');

const target = env.ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT ? `https://localhost:${env.ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT}` :
  env.ASPNETCORE_URLS ? env.ASPNETCORE_URLS.split(';')[0] : 'http://localhost:59447';

const context = [
  "/api",
  "/_configuration",
  "/.well-known",
  "/Identity",
  "/connect",
  "/ApplyDatabaseMigrations",
  "/_framework",
];

module.exports = function(app) {
  const appProxy = createProxyMiddleware(context, {
    target: target,
    secure: false,
    headers: {
      Connection: 'Keep-Alive'
    }
  });

  app.use(appProxy);
};
```

Comment: The credentials must be encrypted via HTTPS or anyone can grab and steal it. So, why do you want to disable HTTPS and go against all components involved? Many such components were designed/developed only with HTTPS in mind.

Comment: @LexLi as mentioned in the question, it is because a remote payment provider connects to a development machine for sending webhooks used in testing the gateway. They don't provide options to ignore if the HTTPS certificate matches the name so I must use HTTP for development testing as per their requirements. Developing with only HTTPS in mind is a fool's errand.

Answer (score 2):

After messing with this for a few days I finally got a working solution to disable HTTPS. There were some other answers that led me astray in terms of what specific config IdentityServer needs and it took me a while to get it down to the bare minimum requirements. Hope it saves someone else a headache in the future.

*Project .csproj file*

```
<SpaProxyServerUrl>http://localhost:44489</SpaProxyServerUrl>
```

*appsettings.json*

```json
{
  "IdentityServer": {
    "Clients": {
      "BnbTools": {
        "Profile": "IdentityServerSPA",
        "RedirectUris": [ "http://localhost:44489/authentication/login-callback" ],
        "LogoutUris": [ "http://localhost:44489/authentication/logout-callback" ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

*launchSettings.json*

```json
{
    "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:59447",
      "sslPort": 44389
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "BnbTools": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5271",
    }
}
```

*.env.development*

```js
PORT=44489
HTTPS=true
REACT_APP_API_URL = "http://localhost:44489"
```